# Deploying LWJGL applications on Mac & Windows

Tags: java, macos, deployment

The LWJGL wiki has [instructions for deploying on Windows](http://www.lwjgl.org/wiki/index.php?title=General_FAQ#Distributing_LWJGL_Applications) as a .exe file, but I can't find anything about how to create a Mac OS X .app bundle.

I could handcraft an Info.plist and build the app myself, but I'd like to have the option of distributing the JRE with my app and I don't think I have the know-how to do so.

Are there any generic Java app --> .app bundle helpers?

Answer (score 3):

I believe Apple supports this function with an App called "Jar Bundler". It transforms a .jar file into a .app package.

Comment: You can use this project to build bundles using Ant: http://informagen.com/JarBundler/